# chain rule with manual substitution

Tags: calculus

Given that I have this function that I want to differentiate.

$$ f(x) = \frac{\cos(x) \sin(x)}{2x+1} $$

I know that I can do this with quotient and product rule, but I would like to understand chain rule fully on this one.

So I say $ z(x) = \cos(x) \sin(x) $ and alter my original problem:

$$ h(x) = \frac{z(x)}{2x+1} $$

Now, would I still do $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ or $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz(x)}$?

If I do the latter, I will get:

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz(x)} h(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz(x)}\frac{z(x)}{2x+1} = \frac{1}{2x-1}$$

If I replace $z(x)$ with what I had before, I will not get the right result at all, I will just get the $f(x)$ back.

Then I tried to apply chain rule, like this:

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz(x)} h(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz(x)} \frac{z(x)}{2x+1} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} z(x) = \frac{\cos(x)^2- \sin(x)^2}{2x-1}$$

Which is not correct either, since the $\cos(x) \sin(x)$ term is missing.

Differentiating against plain $x$:

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} h(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{z(x)}{2x+1} = \frac{z'(x)(2x-1)-2z(x)}{2x-1}$$

Now I did not use the chain rule to get the right result. If I slap another $z'(x)$ on there, as the inner derivative, I get too much.

So how would I use the chain rule the right way in this problem?

Comment: The given function is not a composition (other than the trivial ones). You don't use the chain rule...

Comment: The chain rule is for compositions of functions. If you can't write your original function as a composition, then you can't apply the chain rule. Which functions can you compose to give your original function?

Comment: I do not really see any good function that I could compose the original out of. So I guess I just use no chain rule, since one has to use quotient and product rule anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more digging, I finally came up with a way to do this with the chain rule. The point is, that my function $f$ does not solely depend on $z$ but also on $x$, yielding $f(x, z)$. If I use multivariable calculus on this one, I do get the right result.

\begin{equation}
z(x) = \cos(x) \sin(x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x,z) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, z)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(x, z)
\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} z
\end{equation}

Now here comes up the chain rule.

Plugging the concrete functions in:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{z}{2x+1} =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{z}{2x+1}
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{z}{2x+1}
\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cos(x) \sin(x)
\end{equation}

Now doing the actual deriving:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{z}{2x+1} =
\frac{-2z}{(2x+1)^2}
+ \frac{1}{2x+1}
\cdot (\cos(x)^2 \sin(x)^2)
\end{equation}

Bringing it onto one fraction:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{z}{2x+1} =
\frac{-2z + (2x+1)(\cos(x)^2 \sin(x)^2)}{(2x+1)^2}
\end{equation}

Simplify:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{z}{2x+1} =
\frac{(2x+1)(\cos(x)^2 \sin(x)^2) - 2z}{(2x+1)^2}
\end{equation}

Plugging in $z$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{\cos(x) \sin(x)}{2x+1} =
\frac{(2x+1)(\cos(x)^2 \sin(x)^2) - 2\cos(x) \sin(x)}{(2x+1)^2}
\end{equation}

Now this yields the same result as the regular method. I do see that 12 grade math against second semester university math is not really efficient, but I think I now got the whole concept.

Comment: You could have made things slightly easier for yourself by noting that $\sin\,2x=2\sin\,x\cos\,x$...

Comment: That sounds good. I really need to brush up on trig …

Answer (score 1):

My apologies if this is somewhat off point:

Consider the two functions:
$$
f(x) = \sin\bigl((\cos x)\bigr),\qquad {\rm and}\qquad g(x)=\cos (x) \sin (x)
$$

Are they the same?

Well... How would you compute $f(\pi/4)$, say?

Let's do it: formally substituting:
$$
f(\pi/4) = \sin\bigl(\cos(\pi/4)\bigr).
$$
To simplify this, note that  you have to compute $\cos(\pi/4)$ first (you take cosine  *of* something). $\cos(\pi/4)=\sqrt2/2$, so going back to $f$:
$$
f(\pi/4) = \sin\bigl(\cos(\pi/4)\bigr)= \sin(\sqrt2/2)\approx 0.65\,.
$$

How would you compute $g(\pi/4)$? Let's do it: formally substituting:
$$
g(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4)  \sin(\pi/4).
$$
Here, the first thing we have to do is compute the cosine *of* $\pi/4$  and the sine *of* $\pi/4$.
We obtain
$$
g(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4)  \sin(\pi/4) =(\sqrt2/2)\cdot(\sqrt2/2)=1/2.
$$

$f$ is a composition of functions; it's a "function of a function". That is, there is an "outer function" ($\sin$ in this case) that is evaluated at the inner function's ($\cos$ in this case) value. You use the chain rule to find the derivative of a composition:
$$
\Bigl[ f\bigr(g(x)\bigr)\Bigr]' = f'\bigr(g(x)\bigr)\cdot g'(x).
$$

$g$ is a product of two functions. For this, you of course use the product rule:
$$
\bigl[ f(x)g(x)\bigr]' =f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x).
$$

When differentiating a complicated function, the first thing you should do is determine 
what type it is at the "outermost level" and use the appropriate rule.